# Adding an image to a chart in the background

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, d3.js

consider the jsfiddle example http://jsfiddle.net/5D5eD/8/. I want to add an image in the background which re-sizes itself with change in data values. I was able to add the image in css which was static.

```
body {background-image:url("image.jpg");}
```

I want to add the image but according to change in number of grids it also should scale more or less. How to add such an image ?

Answer (score 1):

Look at http://jsfiddle.net/5D5eD/17/. Try

```
.content+svg {
    background: url('http://www.google.cz/images/srpr/logo11w.png') center center no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
}
```

Now the image resizes with the chart.

Additional and more customizable scaling based on chart data values would have to be done using JavaScript (jQuery). You need to specify how exactly you want the chart to behave to get more precise advice.

Comment: What exactly is not working for you? Make sure you use modern browser with HTML5 support.

Comment: The Background is not changing

Comment: The background reacts to width and height of SVG. How else do you expect background to change?

Comment: It works in the fiddle but when I save it and try opening on the browser the background image doesn't show up(I placed the image in the same folder)

Comment: try:      svg{
    background: url('https://www.google.cz/images/srpr/logo11w.png') center center no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
}